# Multiple axis: using plot vs. line

Tags: matlab, plot

I have 2 sets of data I want to plot on the same graph.

First an histogram:

```
hist(data1);
ax1 = gca;
```

I set the next set of axis, y on the other side

```
ax2 = axes('Position',get(ax1,'Position'),...
    'XAxisLocation','bottom',...
    'YAxisLocation','right',...
    'Color','none',...
    'XColor','k');
```

If I use line() to plot my data it works:

```
line(data2a, data2b, 'Color', 'r', 'LineStyle', '-', 'Marker', '.', 'Parent', ax2);
```

But if I use plot(), the histogram is erased and both axis appear on the left.

```
plot(ax2, data2a, data2b);
```

Can somebody figure out why the second axis is not valid for plot()?

Comment: In general you can help people answer your question by showing a reproducable problem (so we can just copy paste the code). In this case, we would have to guess what `data1` looks like for example. If you need more help or ask other questions, consider adding something like: To see what happens use `data1 = rand(100,1)`

Answer (score 4):

You should check out `doc hold`.

Axes in MATLAB have the 'NextPlot' property, specifying what to do when a new plot-function is issued on this axis.
The default for 'nextplot' is `replace`, meaning that before anything new is drawn, existing plots are erased.
Using `hold(ax, 'on')` or `set(ax, 'nextplot', 'add')` you can specify that new plots are added to the existing ones, instead of replacing them.

The reason that `line` and `plot` behave differently is, that high level functions (like `plot`) respect this axis property, while low-level functions like `line`, `patch` and others do not. They are added to axis in any case and do not remove existing children.

EDIT:
Now I'm noticing that `ax2` should be empty in your case - maybe just try the above nevertheless ;)